# We want calendar attendees to be BCC'd, AND receive notifications about the event in office 365

Tags: json, rest, office365

We are using office 365's api to create events on a user's calendar.  Some of these events are group events.  With those, we want to add the attendees to the event, we want the attendees to receive an email invitation to the event, and we don't want the attendees to be able to see each-other's information.

I have found documentation suggesting to make the Attendee Type = "Resource" to make the Attendees BCC'd.  When I do that, the attendee's aren't notified about the event at all.  This isn't really bcc, since a bcc'd person should still receive an invitation.

With google, we are able to add the attendees like normal, and just set the event's guestsCanSeeOtherGuests to false.  Notification go out, and attendees can only see the host's name/email.

Is there any way to do that with office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Resource attendees do receive invitations. I just tried this with the sample JSON from https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#EventoperationsCreateevents, modified to make the attendee a resource:

```
{
  "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
  },
  "Start": "2015-02-25T18:00:00Z",
  "End": "2015-02-25T19:00:00Z",
  "Attendees": [
    {
      "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "allieb@contoso.com",
        "Name": "Allie Bellew"
      },
      "Type": "Resource"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In my tests, they don't.  Is there possible a setting that needs to be enabled?

Comment: I don't believe so. Maybe the difference is in how we're testing. How are you creating your events? I'm just doing a POST to /Me/Events with the above payload. I've tried sending to both users in the same Office 365 org as well as user's outside of the org, in both cases the attendees received an invite. If you check your Sent Items do you see the invitation?